# My ng-click and ng-if do not work after hosting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, web, visual-web-developer

Friends, I am building a MEAN stack application.
* I have hosted the application at Heroku and database from mLab.

#### When I run it at localhost everything is fine.

Whenever I run it at localhost everything goes fine each and every script runs properly.

## What I want to do?

I need to hide the division on *click* of another division. Each division is linked to another specific division. If one is clicked that division linked div should show and the previous one should hide.

> Everything goes well until I deploy my changes.The code does not work and all the divs appear at one time. Code doesn't work.

### I have used angular and jQuery

- To hide the division I have used angular ng-if
- To call a function I have used ng-click.
  Here's my code:

  ```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('eduController', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.info = 1;
   $scope.info2 = 0;
   $scope.info3 = 0;

   $scope.hideInfo = function() {
      $scope.info = 1;
      $scope.info2 = 0;
      $scope.info3 = 0;
   }

   $scope.hideInfo2 = function() {
      $scope.info = 0;
      $scope.info2 = 1;
      $scope.info3 = 0;
   }

   $scope.hideInfo3 = function() {
      $scope.info = 0;
      $scope.info2 = 0;
      $scope.info3 = 1;
   }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its working fine in your localhost, probably it should do the same at Heroku.

If you had used the webhook at you Github repo to auto fetch the commits in your Heroku app, it would **take some time** for your dyno to fetch those changes and re update your app. Probably you could had waited more and then tried refreshing or cleared your **browser's cache** and then refresh.